# Is the image of a smooth homeomorphism diffeomorphic to the domain?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

This was motivated by the definition of a smooth embedding as an injective smooth immersion that is a topological embedding; I see no reason a-priori for the image of an embedding as defined to be diffeomorphic to the original manifold unless this was true (and if they aren't diffeomorphic then calling it a smooth embedding doesn't seem to make sense to me).

For example, it is well-known that the $x \mapsto  x^3$ is a smooth homeomorphism that is not a diffeomorphism. However, its image is clearly diffeomorPHIC to its domain (both being $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard smooth structure). My question is therefore this: is it true in general that if $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth homeomorphism then $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic?

EDIT: the key thing I somehow missed was the "immersion" part, yes a smooth homeomorphic IMMERSION is a diffeomorphism by the Inverse Function Theorem. But my question still stands.

Comment: Not sure if I am wrong, but you start from a simple question about basic property of immersion/embedding, but end up asking a quite nontrivial question: that if $f :M\to N$ is a **smooth** homeomorphism, then are $M, N$ diffeomorphic?

Comment: It seems to me that, to answer your question (say, negatively), we need to find two homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic manifolds, and somehow show that all homeomorphisms cannot be smooth.

Comment: @ArcticChar: That would be a negative answer to a different question, which is whether if two smooth manifolds are homeomorphic then there is a smooth homeomorphism.  The existence of a smooth homeomorphism is intermediate between the existence of a homeomorphism and a diffeomorphism; OP's question is asking whether it is the same as having a diffeomorphism and your second comment is asking whether it is the same as having a homeomorphism.  Of course, since homeomorphic and diffeomorphic are not equivalent, the answer to at least one of the two questions must be no!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I am quite sure I had seen this question before on MSE (and that I even answered it), after 20 minutes searching I could not find a duplicate. Maybe it was removed. So, here is an answer.

**Proposition.** Suppose that $X, Y$ are smooth 7-dimensional manifolds homeomorphic to $S^7$. Then there exists a smooth homeomorphism $X\to Y$.

At the same time, there are 28 diffeomorphism classes of such manifolds (Milnor's exotic spheres). Hence, you get examples of smooth homeomorphisms between non-diffeomorphic  manifolds.

Let's prove the proposition. Milnor proved that all manifolds $X, Y$ as above are  obtained by gluing two $7$-dimensional balls via a diffeomorphism of their boundaries. Thus, we only need to prove:

**Lemma.** Let $f: S^6\to S^6$ be a diffeomorphism. Then $f$ extends to a smooth homeomorphism $F: B^7\to B^7$ of the closed 7-dimensional unit ball. Moreover $F$ can be chosen to be a diffeomorphism away from the origin.

Proof. Let $\phi(r), r\in [0,1]$, be a smooth strictly monotonic function such that $\phi(0)=0, \phi(1)=1$ and the derivatives of all orders of $\phi$ vanish at $0$ and $\phi'(r)\ne 0$ for all $r\ne 0$. I will be using the polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ on $B^7$, where $r\in [0,1]$, $\theta\in S^6$. Then the desired extension of $f$ is given by the formula
$$
F(r,\theta)=(\phi(r), f(\theta)). 
$$
qed

Edit. I found an answer by Greg Kuperberg [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41984/smooth-bijection-between-non-diffeomorphic-smooth-manifolds) to a similar MO question. Greg claims even more, namely that if two smooth manifolds are PL-equivalent then there is a smooth homeomorphisms between them. However, I could not follow his argument.